# how to session set value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp-classic

I need help...

```
var languageID = document.getElementById('drpLanguage').value;
            //alert(languageID);
            if (languageID == "1") {
                <%Session["languageIDD"] = "1";%>
            } else if (languageID == "3") {
                alert("5");
                <%Session["languageIDD"] = "2";%>
            } else {
                <%Session["languageIDD"] = "3";%>
            }
            <% Session["languageIDD"] = "'+languageID+'"; %>
            window.location = "Default.aspx";
```

This code incorrectly works.Because, LanguageID=3.

Help me....

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't recognize Javascript. You can't mix both code.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET doesn't recognize Javascript code,ignoring javascript "if and elses" it is reading straight in this way:

```
Session["languageIDD"] = "1";
Session["languageIDD"] = "2";
Session["languageIDD"] = "3";
```

So always session will be = "3", because is the last.

If you need to post data to back-end via javascript you need to learn AJAX.

Jquery have an awesome library to work with AJAX, check it out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

*Do not* set session variables from JavaScript code. This can easily be hacked, by executing AJAX call directly.